# How to create a window with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am learning to program with Python 3.6, and would like to ask for help on building a window. It would be greatly appreciated if someone would please show me the basics, like how to make the window, how to make buttons do things, input and output boxes, and stuff like that. I would prefer not to use pyQT or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

The tkinter module is probably the most common Python GUI method.

To make a button:

```
from tkinter import *
tk = Tk()
btn = Button(tk, text="a clickable button", command())
btn.pack()
```

To make an input box:

```
from tkinter import *
tk = Tk()
inputBox = Entry(tk, bd=5)

#to read your box
inputBox.get()
```

To make a label:

```
from tkinter import *
tk = Tk()
label = Label(tk, text="your text here")
```